# How to deploy C# winForm(EntityFramwork) application on LAN network

Tags: sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, deployment, lan

There are dozens of questions like this but none of them resolve this issue.

I have created WinForm application using entityFramework modelFirst approach. I have deployed it using InstallShield and it works perfectly fine.

I have been using **VisualStudio** server explorer for all database related work, not SQL server Management studio.

**Questions**

1. What I simply want is how can I make its database centralised
   through out the LAN network?
2. One computer will act as server and
   will contain that application too, others will just have application
   and use database from server. Do I have to make two builds? or what
   do I do?
3. In-case of change in IP address of server of location of
   database at server? Shall it require new deployment or just some
   changes in connection string?
4. Shall it require some changes in code
   as well to handle exceptions in case of server no-response or
   anything?

Kindly elabore with steps and process, whatever you are suggesting as I am very new to this.

Comment: What's the version of `SQL Server` on server machine?

Comment: Your tags really kind of suck. This is a question about deployment. It's not about SQL Server, or entity framework, and certainly not about "lan".

Answer (score 0):

The general way to do this is to have a ConnectionString that points to the machine running the server. The machine name is used, not the IP address.